# Hibernate Arduino for 12hrs with rtc1302 module

Tags: time, rtc, sleep

ok, Good morning, guys, with a data acquisition project, in this, I get data every 12 hours, even if it's only 12 hours, the arduino gets connected directly, and it's being powered by a 9v battery, for longer life of this battery, to try to hibernate the arduino with real time, using the real time clock 1302, you could help me to make a code for this clock, for I have never used it before! thank you

Comment: Arduino SE is only in English. Would you understand an answer in English?

Comment: Yes, I understand perfectly.

Comment: the translate the question to English with Google translate

Comment: ok,
Good morning, guys, with a data acquisition project, in this, I get data every 12 hours, even if it's only 12 hours, the arduino gets connected directly, and it's being powered by a 9v battery, for longer life of this battery, to try to hibernate the arduino with real time, using the real time clock 1302, you could help me to make a code for this crock, for I have never used it before! thank you

Comment: When you have never used the ds1302, then keep it that way. Don't use it. The ds3231 is a lot better. Which arduino board do you use? For the ds1302, you can start here: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DS1302RTC Setting the arduino uno in sleep mode might not help, there are other components that use current. For sleep mode, you can start here: https://www.gammon.com.au/power

Comment: I have a sleep_pwr_down ready, I was just thinking of adding a few lines of code to configure the ds1302 time, and to do a conditional, to wake up when it's 20 hours and sleep when it's 8 hours, without much complication, it's possible to do that way?

Comment: That is possible. You can even wake up every minute to check the time. Being active for 1% of the time requires little power. If you want to power an arduino uno with a 9v battery, then the sleep mode for the atmega chip has little effect. Did you take a good look at https://www.gammon.com.au/power ? everything you need to know is there. Which arduino board do you use.

Comment: For really low-power consider using a MOS transistor, skip the "sleep-mode" handling and power off the Arduino "completely". https://sites.google.com/site/wayneholder/low-power-techniques-for-arduino

Comment: Hello, sorry for missing out, many jobs in college.
so I'll send you a sleep code, you could take a look and explain to me how to put the conditionals so he wakes up at 8 o'clock to work and when he gets 8 o'clock he goes back to sleep! would help me a lot! thanks for listening.

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 pieces of code and one replacement:

1) Ditch ds1302 and get yourself an RTC with an interrupt pin (like DS3231 which Jot suggests). It will make your life easier.

2) Setup your RTC to fire an interrupt every 12 hours.

3) Since you have successfully implemented a sleep mode, try to wake your Arduino up using a hardware interrupt. See [Nick Gammon's guide for interrupts](http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts), and read carefully about waking your micro with an external interrupt. You can prototype it using a pushbutton, which will either connect your interrupt pin to GND or Vcc. Use an appropriate resistor as well. [This guide](https://www.instructables.com/id/External-Interrupt-in-arduino/) has good information for starters.

To sum up: you'll have your Arduino sleep at all times and your RTC set to fire a hardware interrupt. When fired, the interrupt wakes Arduino, and the interrupt code will handle your measurements.